# How do I drill in to calendar information from the notifications screen on iOS7?

Tags: iphone, calendar, ios, notifications, screen-lock

Lock screen-> pull down notifications, see "Tomorrow, there are 2 events scheduled and the first one starts at 11.30"

but how do I view them?

No amount of poking or swiping will open this up (unlike say weather information)

Is this a bug or is there some buried setting I don't have set?

Yeah yeah, I could unlock the phone and go to the calendar but it sort of defeats the object.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no way to view tomorrow’s events from the Today view. If you’d like to be able to do that, you should [file an enhancement request](http://bugreport.apple.com).